# Help with sockets and Blackberry

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, blackberry

i'm trying to convert a simple irc client written on java to blackberry, it uses sockets, here it is:

```
package seinao;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // The server to connect to and our details.
        String server = "127.0.0.1";
        String nick = "nickname";
        String login = "nickname";

        // The channel which the bot will join.
        String channel = "#oi";

        // Connect directly to the IRC server.
        Socket socket = new Socket(server, 6667);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream( )));
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream( )));

        // Log on to the server.
        writer.write("NICK " + nick + "\r\n");
        writer.write("USER " + login + " 8 * : Java IRC Hacks Bot\r\n");
        writer.write("Hello World!");
        writer.write("PRIVMSG " + channel + "Hello!\r\n");
        writer.flush( );

        // Read lines from the server until it tells us we have connected.
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine( )) != null) {
            if (line.indexOf("004") >= 0) {
                // We are now logged in.
                break;
            }
            else if (line.indexOf("433") >= 0) {
                System.out.println("Nickname is already in use.");
                return;
            }
        }

        // Join the channel.
        writer.write("JOIN " + channel + "\r\n");
        writer.flush( );

        // Keep reading lines from the server.
        while ((line = reader.readLine( )) != null) {
            if (line.toLowerCase( ).startsWith("PING ")) {
                // We must respond to PINGs to avoid being disconnected.
                writer.write("PONG " + line.substring(5) + "\r\n");
                writer.write("PRIVMSG " + channel + " :I got pinged!\r\n");
                writer.flush( );
            }

            else if(line.toLowerCase( ).contains("funciona")){
                writer.write("PRIVMSG " + channel + " Olaz!\r\n");
                writer.flush();
                System.out.println("mermao ta foda");
            }
            else {
                // Print the raw line received by the client.
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

but i noticed there is no java.net.* on blackberry eclipse plugin soo, what should I do ? can someone help me ? what should I use for sockets ? I'm new to java and blackberry programming but i'm learning it quite fast, thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, it's [SocketConnection](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/SocketConnection.html) that you use. Search through the Blackberry API for what you'll need, it'll be way more helpful.